# Ignore Resetting A Field When Checkbox Checked in PHP Form

Tags: php, forms, field, reset

I am trying to write code in PHP where if a certain field is checked...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="OmitDate" value="true" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($OmitDate);?>">
```

...When the Clear button is selected...

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

...It doesn't clear certain fields in the form

```
<input type="text" name="Date" size="140" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(urldecode($Date));?>">
```

It this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not for client side operations.
Use Javascript.

i.e. with jQuery you would do something like:

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $('#textFieldID').val('');
});
```

simple inline javascript can be:

```
<button id="clearButton" onclick="document.getElementById('textFieldId').value='';">Clear</button>
```